apt can't connect to archive.ubuntu.com
I am very new to Ubuntu and I don't really know very much about how Ubuntu works, When I run sudo apt update or when I want to install an app or add repo I get timeout error or faild to fetch, I also tried changing dns.
For example :
Err:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                             
  Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (103.97.84.254), connection timed out

Is there anything to change or reset?

Are you connected to the internet?

Yes I also run ping in.archive.ubuntu.com
PING ubuntu-archive.mirrors.estointernet.in (103.97.84.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 103.97.84.254 (103.97.84.254): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=100 ms
64 bytes from 103.97.84.254 (103.97.84.254): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=99.7 ms
64 bytes from 103.97.84.254 (103.97.84.254): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=100 ms
64 bytes from 103.97.84.254 (103.97.84.254): icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=100 ms

Issue of connecting in.archive.ubuntu.com itself, can be solved it by changing all the URLs to working mirror.
/etc/apt/sources.list
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                            OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                             #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

##### Mirror
deb http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu/ bionic main 
deb-src http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu/ bionic main 

###### Ubuntu Main Repos
#deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse
#deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse


Thanks it worked but I feel mirrors are less stable..
